# Can i deduct that either thumb pressed or finger pressed in android screen programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-touch-event

i started working as android developer. I want to gesture that when someone press on screen, its thumb or finger. Can i do that, let me know if there is any gesture deductor in android?

Comment: No, there is no way for the hardware to distinguish different fingers. You can also operate a touch screen with your nose.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way you can do this. Our hardware is not yet that developed, to distinguish between fingers. Hehe!
Unless it is a fingerprint recognizer. But that's not what you need.